# How to install and use basemap on Google Colab?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-science, data-analysis, google-colaboratory

I'm using google Colab notebook for a project that requires me to plot GPS coordinates on a map. I want to use basemap for this purpose. I tried to import it on the Colab notebook by using
`from mpl_tools.basemap import Basemap`
and it showed up the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-2cb85a2f9bb7> in <module>()
----> 1 from mpl_tools.basemap import Basemap

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mpl_tools'
```

I need to install the basemap module in order to use it. I tried `!pip install basemap` and tried to run it on Colab and that did not work.

Comment: Hi @Suraj , if my answer and fix worked for you, would you mind accepting it? Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
!apt-get install libgeos-3.5.0
!apt-get install libgeos-dev
!pip install https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/archive/master.zip
```

There is a [problem with pyproj 2.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55106691/python-basemap-in-google-colaboratory), so we need to downgrade it:

```
!pip install pyproj==1.9.6
```

restart runtime

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
```

This works for me on Colab on April 7, 2019. I can now set up and plot maps.

Comment: In the meantime, I forgot this answer. Ran into the problem again, and found this answer. Very meta.

Comment: And this one even more

Answer (score 3):

Just for the record, you can also install `basemap` directly with `pip` since the `basemap` version series 1.3.x because now there are precompiled wheels in PyPI (for Windows and GNU/Linux):

```sh
!pip install basemap
```

In case you need the high-resolution datasets, you have to install them manually:

```sh
!pip install basemap-data-hires
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's what worked for me as of today (21st June 2022) on Google Colab:

```
!pip install matplotlib
!apt install libproj-dev libgeos-dev
!pip install https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/archive/v1.2.0rel.tar.gz
!pip install pyproj==1.9.6

from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap as Basemap
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run these scripts

```
!apt install proj-bin libproj-dev libgeos-dev
```

Then

```
!pip install https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/archive/v1.1.0.tar.gz
```

Then you can import

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
```

Comment: If you get it correct please make it as verified answer

Comment: The installation steps worked and it asked me to restart the runtime, which I did. But, when I tried to import the module, it showed the following error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'is_scalar'`