# Python basemap in google colaboratory

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, matplotlib-basemap

I used to use the following commands to install libgeos and basemap in google colaboratory and it worked perfectly until last week.

```
!apt-get -qq install libgeos-dev
!pip install -qq https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/archive/master.zip
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap, cm
```

The error shows

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-f27b0fbc3a52> in <module>()
----> 1 from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap, cm
      2 from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py in 
<module>()
150 
151 # create dictionary that maps epsg codes to Basemap kwargs.
--> 152 epsgf = open(os.path.join(pyproj.pyproj_datadir,'epsg'))
153 epsg_dict={}
154 for line in epsgf:

AttributeError: module 'pyproj' has no attribute 'pyproj_datadir'
```

Is there anyone know how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: It seems to have something to do with the latest pyproj release (2.0.1), which was released on 10.03.2019. Try installing older version of pyproj, eg. `pip install pyproj==1.9.6)`

Comment: It works. Thanks!

Comment: @Chantwaffle this may be worth an actual answer.

Comment: @Chantwaffle: Yes, it works. Do as Thomas Kuhn suggested.

Answer (score 12):

It seems to have something to do with the latest pyproj release (2.0.1), which was released on 10.03.2019. Try installing older version of pyproj, eg. `pip install pyproj==1.9.6`