# AttributeError: module 'pyproj' has no attribute 'pyproj_datadir'

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, matplotlib-basemap

Have had a nightmare downloading basemap, have had so many errors and fixing them, but yet another shows up. I now keep getting the following error:

Using `spyder` I write:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
```

And it outputs:

```
 File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py", 
line 152, in <module>
    epsgf = open(os.path.join(pyproj.pyproj_datadir,'epsg'))

AttributeError: module 'pyproj' has no attribute 'pyproj_datadir'
```

I tried:

```
pip install pyproj==1.9.6
```

but within a large amount of text a line in red says:

```
Failed building wheel for pyproj
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python basemap in google colaboratory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55106691/python-basemap-in-google-colaboratory)

Comment: This didn't work, I've edited my post as above

Answer (score 3):

i was working through the same nightmare of installing basemap in Windows and for this error your fix with

```
pip install pyproj==1.9.6
```

worked for me, but I had to close Spyder (or Jupyter or any IDE). Having it open gave a Permission Error during the pip install. I got this from this post: [Python - PIP install trouble shooting - PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32167418/python-pip-install-trouble-shooting-permissionerror-winerror-5-access-is)